# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'log'

Tags: python

I get the following error while running my python script. Not sure why.

```
  logger.log("Session start")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'log'


# get list of recent mediacenter videos
    videoList = getRecentMCVideos()
    numberOfVideos = len(videoList)
    logger.log("Session start")
    logger.log("Found %d new videos im Mediacenter" % numberOfVideos)
```

Comment: From your statements there is no way to find out what the type of logger could be.

Comment: logger seems to of type `module`, but that doesn't help as Python doesn't have a logger module. The error is happening somewhere in your logger module where you don't have a function called `log` defined. If you post the code from you logger module, we might be able to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Python's `logging` module for your logging needs.
Initialize a logger first, then log to it using `logger.info`/`debug`/`warning`/`critical`. 
like so:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename=filename)
logging.info('Session Start')
```

I strongly suggest you read up on the logger module documentation.
Sources to read:
[Logging Module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)
[Logging Basics](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)